# Small variable width fonts for LCD display

Tags: lcd

I'm looking for a small variable width font that can be used on small LCD screens (in this case a 128x64 pixel screen). I'd like it to have a height of 8 pixels or less, so that the characters will be displayed on one line of the screen. I've tried using programs such as "The Dot Factory" and "GLCD Font Creator", but it seems they are ill-suited for such small fonts.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but there's a lot more to variable width fonts than the bitmaps. If you don't apply [kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kerning_EN.svg) they usually don't look much better than fixed width fonts, which are a million times easier to work with than kerned fonts.

Comment: The minimum horizontal pitch for a nicely-legible fixed-width font is six.  Variable-width fonts can offer comparable legibility with an average pitch of five or even four.  At such sizes, the goal isn't so much to make things look gorgeous, so much as it is to fit the content on the screen legibly.  If nothing else, allow M's and W's to have six-pixel pitch without requiring all the other characters to do so as well (indeed, I've sometimes seen code which stores four pixels of font data for every character, and adds a hard-coded right column and blank column for "M" and "W").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I *do* want to encourage you.  Ahh, this brings back so many happy memories of my childhod, learning to program. This was before the days of the internet of course, so practically everything had to be invented on the fly. One of the things I figured out how to do was handle tiny bitmapped fonts. Then I realised that, if I gave each character as much space as an M needed, then the 'i' would look kind of lost in there. So I had to invent kerning, and how to implement it. It's actually quite easy, so don't let any people put you off.

You didn't say what kind of format you want the font it, so I won't go into that area. Firstly, choose a font. There's a bunch of nice ones on [DaFont](http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php).

I'd start with a single image containing the font.

[image: Tiny font]

Here I have drawn 8x8mm grey squares behind each character, just to show you the spacing. There's no need to have them there really. Each character is left justified. Next, you write a program to import the image, and search through each 8x8 square to find the width of the character. This program converts each character into the binary format that most suits your application, and also stores the width of each character along with the data. When you come to render the characters on the LCD screen, you'll be able to use the width data to position each character right next to the previous one (+1 pixel for a little space).

This kind of very basic kerning is really all you need when you're working with fonts of this size. It's certainly all you need for that particular font, where all of the characters are pretty square.

In fact, you'll be hard pushed to even find a tiny font that needs real kerning. There were none on the first 14 pages of that DaFont link above. Finally, on page 15, I found the [ISL Onyx font](http://www.dafont.com/isl-onyx.font).

[image: ISL Onyx Font]

How to do real kerning on a tiny font? This time, when your program scans each character, it will need to measure the distance between the character and the left and right edges, for each row of pixels:

[image: Kerning a tiny font]

If there's a blank line, then just make the values about half the width of the font, or use the highest value from the non-blank lines.

Now, rendering takes a little longer. When you place each character, you need to compare the first character's right hand column of numbers with the next character's left hand column of numbers.

Add the two columns, and subtract 2. (2 = minimum distance between characters) This gives us the column of numbers in red.

[image: Kerning a tiny font]

Find the smallest number in the column and negate it. This number tells us how many pixels to the right we need to place the next character. In this case, zero. We can place the V right up against the A, and there will still be two pixels between them.

What about two As?

[image: Kerning a tiny font]

This time, the smallest number is -2, meaning that we should place the next A two pixels further to the right to leave two pixels between them.

---

### Storage requirements

How many bytes is all of this going to take up? Assuming all of the characters fit within 8x8 pixels, you'll need 8 bytes to store the pixels themselves. Simple kerning adds one byte per character. Complex kerning only adds 8 bytes. Why 8? Well all of the numbers you need to store are less than 16, so only require 4 bits of storage. Therefore you can store both kerning values for each row in a single byte.

If you had 64 characters you'd need 512 bytes for no kerning, 576 bytes for simple kerning, and 1024 bytes for complex kerning.

Comment: +1, some good stuff!  Reminds me of when I went through a similar learning experience

Comment: @justin - Thanks! There's lots more good stuff on my very old web site: [The good-looking textured light-sourced bouncy fun smart and stretchy page](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/).

Comment: +1! I've done it in the past, more than once, and with multicolors font too, for those (assembly-written!) particle text animation demos... :D

Comment: The kerning approach given will cause characters to touch if an an overhang would sit on the row above the top of the next character.  While it's possible to improve it, I would suggest that in general kerning such small fonts is a waste of time.  Allowing most characters to be narrower than "M" and "W" will increase the quantity of legible text that can fit in a given space; kerning generally won't save much more space.  Further, over-aggressive kerning (e.g. shoving a an apostrophe over an "L") may be worse for legibility than no kerning.

Comment: @supercat - I don't think it would allow them to touch. Must also disagree about the space saving. I've used italic fonts where the 'i' is 1 pixel, and the 'M' is 10 pixels wide! Kerning is *absolutely* necessary here, and in fonts that need it, is noticeably nicer to look at. For example, my old Nokia phone does it for text messaging.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: Slanted fonts can benefit from kerning, but a slanted font with an X-height of seven pixels is apt to be harder to read than a non-slanted one.  At small sizes, letter shapes which would look bad without kerning are apt to be harder to read, with or without kerning, than those which would not.  Note also that in a properly-kerned font, the space between e.g. "AV" should be larger than the space between "OO", and " L' " should leave the apostrophe to the right of the "L".

Comment: If one does not use kerning but simply assigns left and right escapements for each character, then one can draw a string by simply drawing each character in sequence without having to keep any context beyond the position of the drawing cursor.  Adding kerning to the mix makes things adds a level of complication which, *for many applications*, is not really justified.

Comment: @supercat - Agree in general. But I'm not sure what your overall point is. Are you saying that kerning is pointless unless it's perfect? Any amount of kerning is better than none. Even a variable width font is better than fixed width (except for code). (Sorry, I wrote that before your next comment appeared). Sure kerning adds complication, and I wouldn't recommend it it beyond variable width is most circumstances. But I have used it in the past and found that it genuinely improved the text layout.

Comment: @supercat - As for the apostrophe, there is no problem as long as for the blank rows, you simply use the values from the nearest non-blank row. Then the apostrophe will sit at the correct place.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: If one allows arbitrary ("non-gridded") character placement, allowing variable left and right escapement is a relatively easy way to significantly increase the amount of legible text that will fit in a given space.  Adding kerning would represent a bigger increase in complexity which would yield a smaller improvement in text density.  I guess my point would be to recommend that one start with an approach context-free placement of glyphs relative to the drawing cursor, and context-free advancement of the drawing cursor, any only worry about kerning should that be inadequate.

Comment: A reasonable compromise might be to move the graphics cursor one pixel less after drawing each character, but advance it by an extra pixel before drawing the next character if the leftmost column of the new glyph would have any pixels within one position of the rightmost column of the previous one.  That would be fairly easy to implement, and probably yield decent results.

Comment: @supercat - Agreed.

Answer (score 2):

When I worked with the NETMF platform, there was a tools in the SDK (tfconvert) to create a font for the platform starting from any font installed on the PC. I've used it to create a couple of tiny prpoprtional fonts (6-8 pixel height) that worked really well on the 128x64 pixel OLED display on my board. There was also a [nice GUI](http://informatix.miloush.net/microframework/Utilities/TinyFontTool.aspx) to control every parameter of the conversion. I don't know if the format is documented, and if you can use it, but you can give it a look.

NETMF SDK is free to download from microsoft.